# SQL update failing to update database

Tags: c#, sql

This is my code behind for data update. But it is not updating in my database. Don't know why. Any suggestion pls.
I've check the database connection and it is working fine. I didn't declare the connection string using {..}.
Actually I didn't get any error message for the insert. I got an record update message. But in my database, it is not updating.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


namespace StudentDataDisplay2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestData;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Student Data Display Form";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void display_data()
        {
            conn.Open();//establish connection
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from StudentDetails";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Close();

        }
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();//establish connection
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentDetails VALUES (@Name,@Subject)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //add values in textbox1 and store in db
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text; //add values in textbox2 and store in db
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            display_data();

            MessageBox.Show("Record added");
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            display_data();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();//establish connection
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text();
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM StudentDetails WHERE Name= @Name";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //add values in textbox1 and store in db
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            display_data();

            MessageBox.Show("Record deleted");
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //conn.Open();//establish connection
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE StudentDetails SET Name = @Name WHERE Subject = @Subject";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", textBox2.Text);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            display_data();

            MessageBox.Show("Record updated!");
        }

        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();//establish connection
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text();
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM StudentDetails WHERE Name= @Name";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //add values in textbox1 and store in db
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();


            display_data();

            MessageBox.Show("Search completed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NaveenGogineni That isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Yup! U r correct john

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it throwing exception? if yes, post the exception data or describe code's misbehavior!

Comment: @NewBie 1) Is subject a char or varchar in your database? 2) Are you specifying the `Initial Catalog` in the connection string? As a side note, you should declare SqlConnection and SqlCommand within the method body within `using(...) { }` statements. Don't worry about opening too many connections - .NET will connection pool.

Comment: It's not best practice to compare string for updating a row try to use the primary key or auto id of the row

Comment: Subject is varchar type in my database.

Comment: is your display_data working??

Comment: Yes display_data function is working.

Comment: Update will not work if the Subject is not in database.  If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns a zero (no rows changed), then repeat using Insert instead.

Comment: @jdweng yes, it seems like I can update only one way. I need to provide Subject, then I can update the name. How should I implement to update in both ways, i.e, when I provide Name, I can update Subject at the same time?

Comment: @NewBie: Logically speaking, you need a way to differentiate whether A is the "retrieval" value (how to find the row) and B is the updated value (written to the database); or whether B is the retrieval value and A is the updated value. It's not impossible to try and do both at the same time, but it would be incredibly nonsensical from a UI and user perspective.

Comment: If you are updating a student the where should be the student not the subject.  Subject you would be adding or deleting students (not updating).  There are four different types of queries : Select, Delete, Update, Insert.  Since a student has multiple subject how do you update the subject and know which row for the student to change?  You would need additional info like the time the subject was taught to distinguish one subject from another subject.